# self.navigationController is (null) in TableViewController which is on a TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a small app in iOS. After the Login Page, I have a TabBarController and the first tab in it is a TableViewController. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I'm trying to push one view controller for every selected row. The same view controller but self.navigationController is (null) when I print it using an NSLog and I'm not able to push the ViewController. HELP!!

Here's the sample Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here, for example:
    // Create the next view controller.
    PlayerDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[PlayerDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayerDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];
    detailViewController.myImg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    detailViewController.name.text=[self.names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.year.text=[self.draft objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.height.text=[self.height objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.weight.text=[self.weight objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.pro.text=[self.pro objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.ppg.text=[self.ppg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.apg.text=[self.apg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.rpg.text=[self.rpg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);


    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

UPDATE: I got the navigationController to work but now, the data in the pushed view(PlayerDetails) in blank!!

Comment: There's no `UINavigationController` on responder hierarchy. Set you `UITabBarController` or `TableViewController` as a rootViewController of UINavigationController.

Comment: May I please know how I can come around to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's just wrong that you haven't nested your firstViewController inside UINavigationController.

So I guess your code will be seems like this when creating UITabViewController.

```
[tabVC setViewControllers:[vc1,vc2,nil]];//tabVC = UITabViewController
```

And it need to be changed something like below;

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];
[tabVC setViewControllers:[nav,vc2,nil]];
```

Comment: and I have to use nan variable in didSelectRowAtIndexPath of the tableViewController?

Comment: No, what you are trying to do is UITabViewController->UITableViewController->PlayerDetailsViewController which is wrong.  What you need to actually do is UITabViewController->UINavigationController->UITableViewController->PlayerDetailsViewController

Comment: Okay. It works but, now the data I'm sending to detailViewController is lost. I mean to sat that,when I used presentViewController, I could set the values to detailViewController and now, I get a blank display.

Comment: That's nothing related to your current question, and you'd rather to post another question

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the instance of `UITabBarController` is `tabVC` and the instance of `UITableViewController` is `tableVC`.

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc initWithRootViewController:tabVC];
```

or

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc initWithRootViewController:tableVC];
[tabVC setViewControllers:@[nav]];
```

Both will fix your problem.